# How to prevent an unflattering article from ranking for my name?

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I got requested from my client that they were recorded with a hidden camera about something they didn't want public from a TV channel and an article was written about all this where my client's name was also published

The problem is when I search my client's name in the Google I get that article show up in Google’s results as well which is ruining my client's reputation

Is there a way by which I can take it down?

Comment: I'm assuming this website is not yours to control. Please update your answer to clearify this :)

Comment: Google supports legal removal requests. "hidden camera" and "didn't want" and "name published" *may* (depending a lot on jurisdiction) make it worth while trying that ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for what is known in the industry as [reputation management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reputation_management).   There are many businesses with experience in this area that will work on this problem for your client.

If your client is in Europe, it may be possible to use [right to be forgotten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_be_forgotten) laws to force search engines to remove pages from those search results.

In the rest of the world, it is not usually possible to control the placement of a site that you don't own within the Google search results.   Most of the time, the best way to deal with an unflattering search result is to provide better, more relevant results that drown it out and push it off the first page.

Social media sites are often used as part of that strategy.  Facebook and LinkedIn often rank very well when you create public profiles with lots of (more flattering) details.  Just make sure that the two don't contain the *same* information which would cause Google to show only one of them.

A personal website is another good way to get a result higher up in the search results.

Profile pages on participation sites (such as StackExchange) are another good way to get great content to the top of the search results.   If your client already participates in some of the sites, get them to use their real name on their profile.  Some industries have many such forums and sites that you could suggest your client partipate in.

Answer (score 5):

- (Politely) ask website to take page down or change/remove name
- Use a lawyer to find a way to take it down (expensive, not a sure thing)
- Hope this'll blow over, don't make it the [Streisand effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect)
- Make a website/pages which ranks better than theirs to show up first